# ABAP ArchiveLink Database Storgae of Binary Files

Tags: abap

I would like to store created files (for example PDF Documents in binary) via ArchiveLink directly in the database and not on any content server.

I successfully set up the ArchiveLink Content Repository and even store the first file in that repository via a simple report. In this report I used the function module `ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_FILE` and passed it a file path of a file stored locally on my computer, the Content Repository and the Document Type.

Since I however would like to use my Content Repository to store created binary files, I would like to use the Function Module `ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_TABLE`. But implementing this is causing me some trouble.

I tried to upload the same file I used for testing before with the `GUI_UPLOAD` FM (filetype "BIN") and then tried to archive the resulting `BINARCHIVOBJECT` via the Create Table Function module. This is running without any error giving me a `sy-subrc` of 0 and even generating a `ARC_DOC_ID`.

However no entries are written in my Database used for the ArchiveLink and when I try to display the `ARC_DOC_ID` via the `ARCHIVOBJECT_DISPLAY` FM it tells me that it can't load the corresponding file from my Database Storage (Because there of course is no entry for that ARC_DOC_ID).

I would really appreciate any suggestions how I would get this to work.

**Works (For better reading without Exceptions):**

```
PARAMETERS filename TYPE sapb-sappfad LOWER CASE.
PARAMETERS contrep  TYPE toaar-archiv_id.
PARAMETERS doctyp   TYPE toadd-doc_type.

Call Function 'ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_FILE'
  Exporting 
    ARCHIV_ID     = ContRep
    DOCUMENT_TYPE = DocTyp
    PATH          = FileName
  Importing
    ARCHIV_DOC_ID = ArcDocID.
```

**Does not work:**

```
DATA: lt_binary   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tbl1024,
      lv_filename TYPE string,
      lv_length   TYPE i,
      lv_length2  TYPE SAPB-LENGTH.

CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_UPLOAD'
  EXPORTING
    filename   = lv_filename
    filetype   = 'BIN'
  IMPORTING
    FILELENGTH = lv_length
  TABLES
    data_tab   = lt_binary.

CALL FUNCTION 'ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_TABLE'
  EXPORTING
    archiv_id       = ContRep
    document_type   = DocTyp
    LENGTH          = lv_length2
  IMPORTING
    ARCHIV_DOC_ID   = ArcDocID
  TABLES
    BINARCHIVOBJECT = lt_binary.
```

Thanks in advance,

Moritz